How to define a macro that expands to an abbreviation and handles following space correctly?
I want to define a macro that expands into an abbreviation that ends in a period, such as "etc." or "publ.".  The obvious solution \def\publ{publ.} is not adequate:

When \publ appears in the source, it consumes any space immediately following, so \publ date is typeset like publ.date.

When \publ is followed by a period in the source, such as foo \publ. Bar it is typeset like foo publ.. Bar.

The space following the period needs to be either an ordinary interword space or an end-of-sentence space according to some fairly complicated rules.  TeX handles this automatically for most text, but the period ending an abbreviation does not end a sentence and TeX needs to be informed of this.



Might you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

@Micro:  Personally, I do not expect to use LuaLaTeX.  But if there is a particularly terse/elegant/effective solution to this problem that is specific to LuaLaTeX, why don't you provide that as another answer, as service to LuaLaTeX users?

This solution is surprisingly simple.  It defines a macro \pxspace that conceptually expands into the period at the end of an abbreviation, followed by an invocation of \xspace to insert a space when the next source token is a letter (which presumably was preceeded by a space that the macro ate).  You may have to add \usepackage[xspace].
Note that this will incorrectly handle inserting following spaces whenever \xspace does so; in those cases, follow the invocation of your macro with {} and then follow that with a space or not as you would with a macro that ends in \xspace.  Similarly, anomalies with following spaces can be fixed with \@ or \  as they would in non-macro-expanded text.
% Test file for a macro to end abbreviations.

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\pxspace{\@ifnextchar.{\@}{.\@\xspace}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\foo}{foo\pxspace}

\begin{document}

% The cases are:
% Followed by . -- expand into "\@", so the following . is handled as
% sentence-ending.
% Followed by letter -- expand into ".\@" to ensure the generated
% space is normal.
% Followed by punctuation -- expand into ".\@" so that the punctuation
% is not sentence-ending.

\noindent
Followed by a word:  This is an example of foo.\ followed by a word.\\
Followed by a period:  This is an example of foo.  More text.\\
Followed by punctuation:  This is an example of foo., followed by a comma.\\
Followed by other sentence-final punctuation:
    This is an example of foo.:  More text.\\
Followed by punctuation that transmits \texttt{\textbackslash{}spacefactor}: \\
    This is an (example of foo.)\ followed by a word.\\

\end{document}

